# How to tell dash to re-scan apps?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu Dash is blank. How do I get the apps back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103708/ubuntu-dash-is-blank-how-do-i-get-the-apps-back)

After changing my Locale settings I've found that all apps are gone from Dash. How can I tell App lense to re-scan them?