# Ubuntu Dash is blank. How do I get the apps back?

Tags: unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

I restarted Ubuntu, and now the Dash is empty. How do I get it back?

Comment: ... and what version of ubuntu?  what happens if you do a unity reset i.e. `unity --reset`

Comment: its the same. anyway now the terminal is away.

Comment: its the newest version 11.

Comment: 11.10, released last October? Can you take a screenshot and add it to your question?

Answer (score 6):

If the applications stoped showing in Unity Dash than you should first kill this daemon:

```
pkill -f unity-applications-daemon
```

The next step go to your /home directory and press CTRL+H to reveal hidden files. Than search for .cache  folder open it and delete software-center catalog.

Afterwards restart the applications daemon:

```
/usr/lib/unity-lens-applications/unity-applications-daemon
```

If you still don't have anything in the Dash than press ALT+F2 (to bring up run command dialog) type there:

```
unity --replace
```

and run that command. If that didn't do the trick try rebooting computer.