# UBUNTU 12.04 Upgrade - No Programs in Dash

Tags: 12.04, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 after being prompted.  Every did as it should have... so I think.  The install took a very long time so I did not pay too much attention to the install.  Anyways, i just logged in to my computer today (Ubuntu 12.04 now installed) and I have NO programs to choose from.  The Dash Home has NOTHING in it.  I open the software center to find that it is no longer working properly either... meaning, the window opens, but nothing works... nothing is displayed and the search renders nothing at all.  The only programs that run are the default programs in the icon bar.

I have never seen such a problem with Ubuntu before, or Linux for that matter.  I need to get this fixed ASAP!