# Unity Applications lens is empty

Tags: unity, applications-lens

I am using Unity on Ubuntu 12.04. 
For some time now, the Applications lens is completely empty when I open it.
If I search for any applications from the Home or Applications lens, no results show up. I have tried killing and launching the Applications lens as suggested at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/964146), but it did not work. How can I get the applications lens to work again?

Comment: A screenshot could be useful. Also try `unity --reset` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks! Using `unity --reset` worked. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: careful with that unity --reset. It killed my launcher, panel and window surrounds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dash search gives no result](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the terminal try

```
unity --reset
```

and reboot to see the changes.

As far as the mentioned [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-lens-applications/+bug/964146) is concerned ,it was affecting the  `unity-lens-applications-5.8.0-0ubuntu1 (precise)` package and current version stands at `unity-lens-applications (5.12.0-0ubuntu1)` .

It also states that `fix is released` so please update your system , if already up-to-date than ignore this.

Answer (score 5):

I know this has been fixed for the OP, but I had the same problem and it wasn't solved with the suggestions above.  In the end I fixed with:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/unity && unity --replace &
```

My software centre was also broken and that was fixed with:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/software-center
```

From other posts I think the two may be connected hence posting both solutions together here for future searchers.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the command

```
 unity --replace
```

and you don't need to reboot (more convenient). This command restart both Unity and Compiz and clean all the GUI like if she was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think at least one of the previous fixes changes unity settings, setting them to default settings. This may be necessary, but sometimes just a restart of unity has worked for me. From another askubuntu site I found that typing the following in a terminal will restart unity and recover my lenses:

```
unity &> /dev/null & disown
```