# After upgrading to 13.10, no applications are visible in the application lens

Tags: unity, lenses

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and now all icons in the application lens are gone.

[image: Screenshot of missing applications in Unity 13.10 application lens]

This is what I tried so far:

- `apt-get install --reinstall unity-lens-applications`
- `unity --replace` and `unity --reset-icons`
- moving `~/.config` to `~/.config2`
- deleting `~/.cache/software-center` and `~/.cache/unity`

Most of these things have been suggested in this question: [Unity Applications lens is empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173524/unity-applications-lens-is-empty) - but all to no avail.

Comment: I have the same problem and filled [a bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1246281).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is likely because the [unity-scope-home package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-scope-home/+bug/1233029) is not installed.

Try using Software Center to find and install that package, log out and back in to restart Unity, and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Ran `apt-get install unity-scope-home` and all items are back again :) Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think I may have had a similar problem, not sure it was due to upgrading to 13.10 or due to user error. I ended up fixing it as follows:

1. Log out of unity and log in to tty1 (ctrl-alt-f1).
2. "sudo apt-get purge unity" (gets rid of unity and it's settings).
3. "sudo apt-get autoremove" (gets rid of any leftover packages that unity depended on, like the lenses and such.)
4. "sudo reboot" and log into tty1 again afterwards.
5. "sudo apt-get install unity"

Bit drastic, but it worked.

Comment: This knocked the life out of Ubuntu.