# No HUD results when Alt+searching in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, hud

Frankly, I'm not actually sure how long this feature hasn't been working for as I never used it much, but I upgraded to 13.10 recently and the HUD doesn't show any results for any applications. The dash is working great, no issues there. I'm assuming I just need to uninstall and reinstall some package, but any idea what that package is?

Thanks!

Comment: What about *locate HUD from term? OR maybe whereis HUD. *apt-cache search HUD is perhaps your BEST bet. Synaptic turns up no results?

Comment: synaptic turns up several results -- I have hud, libhud-client2, libhud2, and libhud-gtk1 installed, but rather than pull them out at random I was wondering if anyone had a better idea :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [After upgrading to 13.10, no applications are visible in the application lens](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367181/after-upgrading-to-13-10-no-applications-are-visible-in-the-application-lens)

Comment: nope, that's an issue with the dash, not the HUD. as I said, my dash is fine.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/375374/hud-in-1310-no-longer-returns-out-of-focus-applications-or-system-commands/379128#379128