# HUD in 13:10 no longer returns out of focus applications or system commands

Tags: unity, 13.10, hud

I upgraded to 13:10 having run 12:04,12:10 and 13:04  and now the HUD is not entries from out of focus applications or, more importantly for me, system commands such as lock, suspend etc.

is this expected behaviour? is there any way to change it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behaviour due to a design decision (currently referred to, but not yet referenced, in [this launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hud/+bug/1165420) - see comment #8 by Ted Gould).

Sadly, I have not come across a method of changing it back.  There are two partial workarounds I'm aware of:

- [Gnome Do](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gnome-do/) still works with Unity, and can allow for lock, shut down etc.  There are almost certainly some indicator functions it won't do out of the box, but it may well be enough for your needs.
- You can access the indicator menus using the keyboard by doing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> followed by <kbd>Left</kbd>.  If you want shut down then just do <kbd>Up</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, otherwise use the cursor keys to navigate.  Nowhere near as convenient as the old HUD, but might be useful enough for you.