# Ubuntu 15.10 No Lenses

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I upgraded from Ubuntu `15.04` to `15.10` and Unity Application Lenses do not work.

[image]

I have tried:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-scope-home`

`sudo unity --reset`(no more supported).

`sudo unity --replace`

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Unity, tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173524/unity-applications-lens-is-empty) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367181/after-upgrading-to-13-10-no-applications-are-visible-in-the-application-lens).

Any suggestions?

Is it me, or is this a bug in Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: Try: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254775

Comment: @Zacharee1Does not work, anymore suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this has something to do with the user. I say this because if you log in Guest or create a new account, you'll find that the icons appear. I do not why this happens, but I suggest you move all your stuff to a new user and delete your old account. That's what I did, seems like it's one of the most practical solutions.

Comment: Will do so. If only there was a way to know. Oh well, that's a story for another day.