# My unity dash problem

Tags: unity-dash

My unity dash button somehow wouldn't show up applications for some no reason.
I also tried the applications ( middle-down ) But it still wouldn't show up applications. I currently use 15.04.

Comment: I am using 15.04 If I did that it would say unknown command.

Comment: You have much bigger problems if reinstalling a package is an unknown command.

Comment: From the linked question, please reinstall unity-lens-applications and unity-lens-files.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your filter setting on the top left side of your search / application screen. Here you can select what types of lenses you want to see.

Comment: my filters have applications done... If that made sense any ways it activated but still no applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run:

> unity --reset

from the terminal.
This resets the unity settings to default.
See also:
[Unity application lens is empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173524/unity-application-lens-is-empty)