# Unity dash won't display applications and system settings doesn't open either!

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

I have changed the language of ubuntu to my local but after logout and login the Dash doesn't display any app. and if I want to open system settings from system menu it doesn't open either!

[image]

I've tried many solutions like: restart the computer, `rm ~/.cache/software-center -R`, `unity --reset &`, `unity --replace &`, re-install `unity-place-applications` and `unity-place-files`, `~/.local/share; rm -rf zeitgeist`, `sudo chmod 774 /usr/share/applications/*`

None of these had solve the problem. What should I do?

Comment: Please answer, the Ubuntu 12.10 will not release until October so I have to stick with this til then but now no apps how I can work with this!! T_T.

Comment: What locale did you change to? Does it use a different encoding?

Comment: Did you consult this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale/ ?

Comment: yes I guess it have, it's "Arabic Language" locale I've changed the language from the User Accounts option. I don't know why it did this I mean I've change to this month ago and nothing like this happen!

Comment: I had also install an app call GFeedLine before this happen it was a .deb package and I have install it without any error using Gdebi...

Answer (score 0):

I've fix this by fresh install and sadly I've lose all my data because of this :(

Comment: Reinstallations don't remove data by default!

Comment: well looks like I didn't know about this "default" thing so I caused the lose of all my data but hey Ubuntu One is always there to rescue right :)

Comment: by author you mean the one who write this question right?! because if you mean so that will be me I've ask and answer my own question because no one else do!