# How can I call system settings app from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, system-settings

How can I call system settings app from the terminal?
example if I want to run Gnome PPP I just type:

```
$ Gnome-PPP
```

and it will Open, so how I can do this to run system settings tool?

> -[related!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174923/unity-dash-wont-display-applications-and-system-settings-doesnt-open-either)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The System Settings app can be started with the `gnome-control-center` command.

Comment: when I run this it show me the flowing error: `Bus error (core dumped)`

Comment: I had kind of a similar problem in archlinux. Maybe, try: `MALLOC_CHECK_=1 gnome-control-center`. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=140131 You should also upgrade your system if not already done.

Comment: well thanks but it show me the same Bus error (core dumped) nothing else!