# Dash Home in Ubuntu 12.04 is empty!

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

When I press Dash Home in my Ubuntu 12.04 Dash window is empty and when I type names of my basic apps (Firefox,...) it doesn't find it at all that means that I can,t use it. The question is how to reinstall dash or how to fix it another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open the Terminal.
Now type these commands:

This will remove the components for Unity:

```
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get remove compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get purge compiz*
```

Now this will reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Hope this helps you!