# are there any way to find the true package which I want to uninstall on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, uninstall

Uninstalling using the method:

```
dpkg --list
sudo apt-get remove “package-name”
sudo apt-get purge “package-name”
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

is a beautiful way, but the problem is in searching for the package which I really need to uninstall inside all of this long `dpkg --list` , and this is not the fatigue, you will get enough fatigue when looking for the true name of the true package which you want to remove.

-are there any way much easier than this?
-are there any software like Iobit uninstaller which is on Windows? mean: software for uninstalling programs on Ubuntu?
-are there any way to get the true name of the package which we want to remove?

Comment: So you don't know the name of the package. What DO you know about what you want to remove? Application name? Command?  Something Else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask the packaging system. For example, if I wanted to uninstall the `bluefish` program, I would do:

```
walt@fox:~(0)$ type bluefish
bluefish is /usr/bin/bluefish
walt@fox:~(0)$ dpkg -S $(type -p !$)
dpkg -S $(type -p bluefish)
bluefish: /usr/bin/bluefish
walt@fox:~(0)$
```

In this case, the `/usr/bin/bluefish` binary is in the `bluefish` package.

Comment: Thanks waltinator, it worked, could you explain those commands?

Comment: @sam-islam: Read  `man bash` for `type` and `$()`, read man `dpkg` for `dpkg -S`.

Answer (score 0):

It's much less fatiguing to use a GUI application that permits you to keyword search and scroll so that you can view groups of packages containing the same keyword together, all of which are marked by a green filled checkbox if they are installed. Try searching for *libreoffice* in synaptic and you will see that there are many libreoffice packages in many different languages, but only the LibreOffice packages that are installed have a green filled checkbox. You can also narrow the search by categories such as *Installed* or *Installed (local or obsolete)* as marked by the mouse cursor in the left pane of the below screenshot.

[image: Synaptic Package Manager]

To install Synaptic in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

To open Synaptic from the terminal type:

```
pkexec synaptic
```

You will be asked to authenticate with your user password in order to launch Synaptic.

This works most of the time if the package name is similar to its application name. If it isn't try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448844/finding-package-name-of-installed-software/448848#448848).

Comment: What if the package name was not the same name of the program which I installed, for example I have 7z file archiver installed, but I can't find it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/448844/finding-package-name-of-installed-software/448848#448848