# screen flickering with hovering unity and dash doesn't open

Tags: 16.04, compiz, unity-dash

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

after I shut down the laptop with power button anytime I hover any icon on the left side launcher the screen is flickering(all of the launcher gets hidden for a while and gets back and the applications are still there) and the dash is not opening .the shut down in the menu on top right does not bring the window which makes the laptop shut down.

I found this on google:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2061180

It requested the following commands:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release  
uname -a    
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga   
env | grep DESK
```

the result of commands are:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
```

---

```
Linux amirali 4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Fujitsu Limited. Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [10cf:150a]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

---

```
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
```

[Dash Home will not open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445342/dash-home-will-not-open)

the same solutions didn't work. I used ccsm to restart the unity. But it again flickers with hovering the luncher's icons.(the launcher gets hidden for a while)

the error report from ubuntu is as following:
 compiz crashed with sigsev

Comment: what's "the same solution"? (What exact commands did you run?)

Comment: @unhammer I used ccsm command to disable and reenable the unity. And tried to find a driver which was missing but couldnt find any.

Comment: Also there is no nvidia in vga same as the one in the link.

Comment: Sounds like this bug that came out early January 2018:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults

Comment: After running sudo apt-get upgrade -y the bug was fixed.