# I lost all applications on Dash Home and  Software Centers buffers, how to retrieve it?

Tags: launcher, software-center, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

I am using 12.04 in EeePC netbook. I keep on receiving a software update and installed it.

This evening, as I try to open the Dash Home and search for the installed application such as Skype, calculator, Microsoft wWord, etc., nothing appears, everything is gone. Only the files and folders in my Home remains. I also tried to open the Ubuntu Software Center but it buffer.

I don't have any idea how to fix this. Please help me restore all the installed applications.

Comment: Try `unity --reset` and reboot.

Comment: please..how to do that?

Comment: Open terminal by `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type it or through TTY `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and type it, then `Alt+F7` to exit  and reboot.

Comment: i did the above instruction and then there's a long response..too long that I can't post it here..after the long response I press alt+f7 then below is the response

Comment: ^[7
WARN 2012-08-29 19:18:00 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:283 Calling method "InfoRequest" on object path: "/net/launchpad/lens/video" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `com.canonical.Unity.Lens' on object at path /net/launchpad/lens/video
WARN 2012-08-29 19:18:00 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:283 Calling method "SetViewType" on object path: "/net/launchpad/lens/video" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such

Comment: interface `com.canonical.Unity.Lens' on object at path /net/launchpad/lens/video
WARN 2012-08-29 19:18:24 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:182 Unable to connect to proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for com.canonical.Unity.Lens.Applications: Timeout was reached
WARN 2012-08-29 19:18:24 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:182 Unable to connect to proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for com.canonical.Unity.Lens.Applications: Timeout was reached

Comment: the terminal window didn't exit and when I try to close it this response appeared: There is still a process running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it..what should be the next thing to do?...please do help!...:)

Comment: you did something to disable the dbus services that listen for unity lenses...that's what the error messages are expressing.