# Upgrade to 12.04 results to empty Dash, no date & time either on the top panel

Tags: indicator, unity-dash, privacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

I've upgraded from Ubuntu netbook remix something to 12.04 LTS, and I've got two issues. (Got an Asus eeePc 32bits, Intel 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2 and Intel Atom CPU N270 @ 1.6Ghz x2)

1. Nothing in the Dash. Only the "home" tab, other tabs are missing. No search results whatsoever.
2. Missing elements in the system panel, privacy and date & time. No date & time on the right corner either.

I've tried to reset unity with the terminal but the process was a whole mess full of errors. It did show date & time in the system panel (not on the top-right corner) while the process was going on in the terminal. But then it was such a mess (no more icons on the right corner amongst other things), and the process wouldn't complete, so I had to reboot the computer and get Unity as before, still no date & time and privacy.

Comment: no battery state icon either, in both system panel and top-right corner

Comment: alacarte crashes when I try to launch it; I reinstalled it using the terminal, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade only works from the previous version or the previous LTS version. Which means if you did not have 11.10 or 10.04, your upgrade will be a mess, or actually wont happen at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I've installed ubuntu 3 years ago, I've always been upgrading it as soon as I was asked to do so. So, it's always been perfectly up-to-date, and 12.04 lts upgrade was automatically suggested to me.
But everything works fine (programs, files, etc.) except these little issues.
UPDATE: the dash is now working perfectly. I followed some advices grabbed in other topics and it worked, but I can't even find again what fixed the issue...

So, the only problem left is: some elements are missing in the system panel: how can I reinstall them all? "Energy, privacy, date&time"