# Do i remember right that the dash had a start page with big icons?

Tags: unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

My dash start page worked perfectly for the first 2-3 months.. now it is exactly like this for about 2 months:

[image: dash start page]

Bug? Should i report it? Is it already reported? Anyone else has the same problem?

Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:    12.04

unity:
  Installed: 5.14.0-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.14.0-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 1):

Its not a bug. Install any Ubuntu tweaking programs to control it, for example Myunity.
This picture shows you that you can change the dash size.

[image]

Choose Dash size to desktop to restore to original size.

To install Myunity open a terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

Comment: I always had myunity: see my settings still the same: http://i.imgur.com/0ltoc.png