# Dash empty and blank Software Center

Tags: unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

I've Ubuntu 12.10.1 LTS x62 fresh of installation...
My dash is empty, search doesn't work and applications list is empty.

If I run the Ubuntu Software Center it freeze in a blank screen.

I tried with:

- restart
- reinstall of unity packages
- deleting ~/.local/share/zeitgeist folder
- other tricks found in the other askubuntu answers

**UPDATE:**

From ~/.xsession-errors

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/francesco/.compiz/session/10699c9c27649d05db134910329935534100000027470033"
Initializing session options...done

(compiz:2813): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed

** (zeitgeist-datahub:3070): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
```

**EDIT:**

Deleting **.cache** folder solves the Ubuntu Software Center blank screen issue, thanks to jokerdino!!

Comment: Do you have something relevant in `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: xsession-errors added to main question :)

Comment: Try removing `~/.cache/software-center`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video
```

If not, use:

```
zeitgeist-daemon --replace
```

Comment: nada... packages are already the newest version.

Comment: Ok... what it says for: `zeitgeist-daemon --replace` ?

Comment: Good!! The *zeitgeist-daemon --replace* command solves my question.. Thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, `zeitgeist-daemon --replace` gave me this error: `[14:40:07.168071 WARNING]  zeitgeist-daemon.vala:546: Não foi possível iniciar automaticamente o D-Bus sem X11 $DISPLAY`, but the `sudo apt install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video` solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice to not need to reboot after your solution. I created a new question in order to discover how to refresh Dash after these packages you suggested have been installed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459749/empty-dash-fixing-how-to-not-reboot