# Empty Dash fixing: how to not reboot?

Tags: unity, 22.04, unity-dash

I had the famous and long-lasting Dash bug in which no softwares are shown when pressing the "Windows" key on the keyboard, on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Searching also did not return any results.

[I fixed it by using this command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195199/dash-empty-and-blank-software-center): (notice that the solution, and so the bug, is at least 11 years old already!)

```
sudo apt install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video
```

The problem is: it needs the machines to be rebooted in order to Dash to reflect these changes.

But there are so many machines here with this problem, that it would be a pain to reboot all of them just to refresh Dash after fixing it. And all machines are on dual-boot with Windows, and this would force me to manually instruct each one to boot on the correct Operating System, login again, etc.

**Question:** which command is the best to refresh Dash after fixing it?

`shutdown -r now` and any other that imply rebooting is automatically disqualified from this contest.

[image: This is Dash]

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu dock doesn't have a process. So I don't think it's going to work. You can try `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

Comment: @Rishon_JR This suggestion does not solves the problem. But thank you for trying. If you have another idea, feel free to add it here.