# Ubuntu dash not searching for files

Tags: files, unity-dash, lenses, search

i've just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and i've found that in the dash i can't look for files that i haven't opened yet, eg: I have a huge collection of pdf files and when i look for them on the dash i can only find the ones i've opened. How can I correct this?Is there any way of changing the Dash search settings?

Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly are the pdf files? Are they in the home folder? If not, then where?

Comment: check out this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result

Comment: @mikewhatever They are all in the Documents folder

Answer (score -1):

From terminal run `sudo updatedb`.

Comment: Could you include *why* this would help? Does updating the `locate` database indeed help here?