# Dash is not searching all files

Tags: unity, unity-dash, encryption, search

I have two laptops running Ubuntu 13.04. The only difference between them is that one has an encrypted home folder and I guess it is the reason preventing the dash to index, search and display all files but the opened. I have already tried `sudo updatedb` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236351/ubuntu-dash-not-searching-for-files) and elsewhere, and deleted the cache folder (as well as the program and config files) of USC as stated in a well reputed [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result). After logout or reboot, the behavior is the same. Question is: how can I get the searching dash in the second case?

Laptop 1

[image]

Same search, laptop 2 (encrypted home)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files scope relies on two main data sources to return results:

1. Zeitgeist is used to return recently used files.
2. The system `locate` database is used to search your entire home folder.

If you have chosen to encrypt your home folder, then your home folder will be an `ecryptfs` mount when you are logged in.

The default configuration for updating the `locate` database in `/etc/updatedb.conf` skips `ecryptfs` filesystems.

You can change this configuration by editing the `PRUNEFS` variable in that file, but note that **this will leak the names of files in your home folder onto non-encrypted storage**.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is currently a solution (beside [this alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20821/using-locate-on-an-encrypted-partition)) that will let you search your files in the dash and keep their metadata private.

If you add the command `alias updatedb-home='export LOCATE_PATH="$HOME/mlocate.db" && updatedb -l 0 -o $HOME/mlocate.db -U $HOME'` you then can run `updatedb-home` periodically to update db, or add it also to `.bashrc` to run it on every login.

Comment: I'd like to thank your answer. Now I can search the files as expected.