# Ubuntu dash 13.10 not searching files?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

This seemed to help but the dash is still not searching files. It however does search folders.

Document Directory searches fine.

Download directory doesn't search correctly even though I just just added items (I did open the items because I read unity doesn't index items unless they are opened).

Things I have tried:

```
rm ~/.cache/software-center -R
unity --reset &
```

Download Directory contains:

```
/home/username/Downloads/Untitled Folder
/home/username/Downloads/empty
/home/username/Downloads/world
/home/username/Downloads/test.pdf
```

Searching the dash with the keyworld "Downloads" yields: 1 folder "Downloads"

Document Directory Contains:

```
/home/username/Documents/HELLOWORLD
/home/username/Documents/EmptyDoc
/home/username/Documents/HelloWorld.java
/home/username/Documents/tryingtosearch
```

Searching the dash with the keyworld "Documents" yields: 1 folder "Documents":

```
/home/username/Documents/HELLOWORLD
/home/username/Documents/EmptyDoc
/home/username/Documents/HelloWorld.java
```

but "tryingtosearch" is not there. Is this a file indexing issue?

If it matters I did run this code previously:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

and this code:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps*
```

^This messed up my desktop and I had to fix it. I don't recall what command I used to fix it but I think it was this: `sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

This seemed to fix it:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Should I really have to run that each time though? Obviously one could create a bash script but that is disappointing if one has to run that each time.

I have tried the solutions on this page:

- [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dash search gives no result](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

Comment: Not a duplicate; I have tried the solutions on that page. Also, they are running Ubuntu 11.10, and I am running Ubuntu 13.10 with the new Smart-Scopes feature.

Comment: `updatedb` is automatically run once a day. You only have to run it manually when you need to update it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss --reinstall install unity-scopes-master-default

sudo apt-get -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss --reinstall install unity-scopes-runner

sudo apt-get -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss --reinstall install unity-scope-home
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo updatedb` fixed this by re-indexing unity's search engine. The search now searches anything after running `sudo updatedb`.