# Dash search does not find all of my files

Tags: unity-dash, search, scopes

For example:

I create the file X.odt and then export it as pdf.
After I click on dash search (the files filter is active) X.
The X.odt appears with no problem but the X.pdf does not.

That happens always. What should I do?

Comment: Something interesting. I tried this in 12.04 dash and it's like @Orestis says, x.odt appears but x.pdf does not. I tried searching using synapse (`sudo apt-get install synapse` if you want to install it) and both appear. Is this a bug?

Comment: But after you open the x.pdf file once, it suddenly becomes visible in Dash results.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, run `sudo updatedb` in terminal. It will take a couple of minutes to finish but at the end you will have your x.pdf file show up in the dash without logging out, restarting unity or erasing the zeitgeist databases which will make you lose all you activity information.

Source: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+question/195718

Another interesting question I found is [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result).

Comment: I will download synaspe and I will give it a try. But this is a bug, right?

Comment: Edit: Btw that happens only in the pdfs... If I create the odt and the same time the pdf the odt will be visible....