# Unity Dash Does not Shows any Applications. Searching Applications for ever

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I installed the day before a set of packages for GCC-4.8.2 compiled on my machine Ubuntu 12.04. After the installation of the 52 packages I got some broken dependencies with i386 libraries (Multi-Arch) I did not compile at that time as I had compiled the amd64 version. As soon as the Update Manager displayed the red icon (broken packages) I noticed that the Unity Dash was unable to show any applications. I shut down my PC for the night in that state. The following day I fixed all the i386 (Mulyi Arch) libraries. Then the Update Manager was working again, but the Unity Dash is still unable to show any application ...

I tried to purge and re-install `unity-lens-files` and `unity-lens-applications` then restarting the PC. That didn't change anything to the Unity Dash behavior. It looks like there is somewhere a bug or some configuration on which it relies is corrupted. Everything else is working fine so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for disturbing people here ... This low tech failure had me on my nerve.

The solution was to clear the software-center hidden folder ~/.cache and to reset unity. This is one of the solution proposed on [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result). However in order to be able to restore the cache in case this does not work it is better not to remove it first but to rename it to -bak for exemple:

```
$ mv ~/.cache/software-center{,-backup}
$ unity --reset &
```

Or `<Alt> <F2>` and type `unity` (to reset not using a terminal).
After checking's it's working

```
$ rm -r ~/.cache/software-center-backup/
```

Comment: ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 14.10. unity reset option is now deprecated. 
If software-center cache data caused this issue, by taking a backup & removing the folder should allow unity to function as usual.

```
$ mv ~/.cache/software-center{,-backup}
```

then after few seconds, try using the dash again. We should get back the applications listed.

If you are struggling to manually invoke any general apps., press `Super + N` to open folder and navigate to `/usr/share/applications`. Here you should find general applications listed.

Once the unity is back, analyse log files in `~/.cache/software-center-backup` to understand what went wrong.