# No search results

Tags: unity, 20.04, unity-dash

I've troubles since updating to version 20.04 LTS with

- no search results and
  [image]
- freezing desktop after about 1 hour. (I guess this could be a symptome related to no search results. Just a hint if helpfull.)

I've already researched for answers like this "[Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)" but I couldn't fix this issue.

Screenfetch tells me this:

``````
                          ./+o+-       daniel@linux
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 20.10 groovy
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.8.0-43-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 15h 10m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2920
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.0.17
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 3286x1080
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: Unity 7.5.0
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Compiz
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Ambiance
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 64G / 454G (15%)
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: Intel Core i5-3320M @ 4x 2,6GHz [69.0°C]
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
                   ````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 15448MiB / 15881MiB
                          `oo++.
``````

What can be the solution to fix this (and is the issue because of the update)?

Comment: "freezing desktop after about 1 hour" — You are still using the Unity desktop with Compiz. I seem to have the impression that Unity (unfortunately) is not developed any more? Maybe you need to install a supported desktop environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is (so) the best practice solution I changed to GNOME 3.38.3. Now everything works fine. Live long and prosper Unity.